# Iterator on Mapwritable of MapWritable

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, iterator

I have in Java  (with map-reduce hadoop library) :

```
MapWritable<String, MapWritable> mw;
```

I need to get an Iterator on all the MapWritable value of mw, but how?

I can write:

Iterator it = ((MapWritable) mw.values()).what?

I can't replace "what?" with iterator.

If i write:

```
mw.values().iterator();
```

I have Iterator and not of MapWritable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`mw.values()` return a `Collection<MapWritable>`, if you need to iterate on values of mw you can do it like you said `mw.values().iterator()`. If you need to iterate on your mw you can use `mw.entrySet().iterator()`